# Change Date default to_s format in the scope of library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, date-formatting, ruby-2.4

I want all of the dates in the scope of the library to have a common format (`"%d.%m.%Y"`) instead of the default (`"%Y-%d-%m"`). For now I have come up with 3 different approaches (and I don't like any of them) to accomplish what I want. All of them are represented below in order from most to less painful:

1. explicitly define all the attributes with dates and convert them in the necessary format in the exporter;
2. redefine `to_s` method for each `Date` instance with the necessary format;
3. define a custom descendant of a `Date` class with a custom `to_s` method.

**Additional information**:

- The initial object can have up to 3 nestings with attributes of `Date` type on each of them;
- The names of the attributes of `Date` type can vary;
- I am using Virtus gem.

The question is as follows:

Is there a better way to handle the issue I am struggling with *(and if not, what is the most elegant way to go between the ones that are already represented above)*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another module with a refinement to `Date::to_s`

```
module MyDate
  refine Date do
    def to_s
      # here goes your implementation of to_s
    end
  end
end
```

And then:

```
 class NeedsCustomDateFormat
  using MyDate
  # All Date instances will have the custom to_s
 end
```